# Pass variable-length arguments to another function expecting the same?

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

How to code this right in Scala?

```
def myFun(strings: String*) = {
  // do something...
}

def myWraper(strings: String*) = {
  // do something else and then call myFun with the dame input
  myFun(strings)
}
```

I've tried putting an asterisk like

```
def myWraper(strings: String*) = {
  // do something else and then call myFun with the dame input
  myFun(strings*)
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
 myFun(strings: _*)
```

You need to tell it to split `strings` up across the varargs.

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was looking for. I just could not remember how was it to be written. I've tried the underscore too, but it's of all these 3 symbols :-)