# How to pass scala array[object] to java function parameters

Tags: java, scala

java code

```
public void insertRow(Object... fieldList) {
  for(int i = 0; i < fieldList.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(fieldList[i]);
  }
 }
```

Scala code

```
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
    insertRow(args)
}
```

As show above, I want to call a method which write in java and has a non-fixed parameters. when I pass parameter in scala Array, it the fieldList.length is always 1 and just get the whole args not the element in scala array. so could someone tell me how to convert a scala array to java or how to pass a scala array to java ?

Comment: Have you tried just adding a type ascription? i.e. `insertRow(args: _*)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass variable-length arguments to another function expecting the same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168101/pass-variable-length-arguments-to-another-function-expecting-the-same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for in this case is:

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  insertRow(args: _*)
}
```

Notice the `_*` syntax used to call the vararg method.